# How can i click the following Button with puppeteer?

Tags: automation, click, puppeteer

I'm trying to click a button on a website with puppeteer but it doesn't work for me.

Element-info:

```
<button aria-label="Alles akzeptieren" role="button" data-testid="uc-accept-all-button" class="sc-gtsrHT gqGzpd">OK</button>
```

My Code:

```js
async function checkout(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    
    await page.goto(product_url);
    await page.waitFor(3000);
    await page.click("Button[class='sc-gtsrHT gqGzpd']", elem => elem.click());

}
```

Error Message:

Error: No node found for selector: Button[class='sc-gtsrHT gqGzpd']
at Object.assert (C:\Coding\Ticket-Bot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\assert.js:26:15)
at DOMWorld.click (C:\Coding\Ticket-Bot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\DOMWorld.js:277:21)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async checkout (C:\Coding\Ticket-Bot\bayern.js:14:5)

Pictures:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYOnx.png (Button Info)
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZSJt.png (Button)

what is the correct code so that the button will be clicked?

Comment: `await page.click("button.sc-gtsrHT.gqGzpd");` the classes seem autogenerated, so are likely quite unstable. maybe you should use another property of the button to identify it.

Comment: Can you give an example how to do it?

Comment: If it try it with xpath i get following error

(node:9400) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at checkout (C:\Coding\Ticket-Bot\bayern.js:15:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

Comment: That's the tricky part of web scraping or any frontend-automazation. I'd open the page in your browser's dev tools and then figure out a suitable CSS selector. What can be considered "stable" is different from page to page. But those seemingly random alpha-numeric IDs are usually changing between builds. So as per answer below, use more static properties or even the button's text (here, you would need to split between getting a reference to the button and clicking it, though)

Comment: How can i click the button by using the text? The text ist just "OK".

Comment: What's `product_url`? Based on the button here, there's no problem clicking it -- the issue must be something to do with the page you're manipulating, which we haven't been shown. Make sure to `waitForSelector` first before attempting a click.

Comment: There are different ways to retrieve the button from its text. You can,e.g., use `.evaluateHandle()` and pass it a function that gets all buttons first and then filters to the one with the right text (assuming it's the only "ok" button on that page). For triggering the click, see the second example in the docu: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args

Answer (score 2):

You get the error due to the element does not exist on the page, it may be caused by the fact that CSS classes are autogenerated as @Sirko suggests.

You can even inspect the element's class name in DevTools if you launch puppeteer in headful mode.

You will need to find those selectors that will remain the same, e.g.:

```js
await page.click('[aria-label="Alles akzeptieren"]');
```

```js
await page.click('[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]');
```

*Note:* I am not sure if you need `elem => elem.click()` in the click options.